# Is there a way to visualise football data as a timeline in one game?

Tags: dataframe, powerbi, data-visualization, visualization

I am busy with a project extracting data from FIFA (football simulator) and visualising it in PowerBI (preferably). I was looking into how I would be able to visualise my dataset in a way that i would be able to 'slice' throughout a game seeing when goals are made, which player is in possession, what the positions are of the players etc. I have the following dataset:

[image: Example of the Dataset]

In here, ball_coordinates, dynamic_team/opponent give the pixel coordinates of the ball in the field and the players on the field respectively.

Now I would like to visualise this information in PowerBI such that I could 'slice' through the game checking when a goal is scored e.g. and seeing where the players and the ball is located on that moment. To give a quick overview, I want it to look something like the following:

[image: Visualisation slicer]

I was wondering if anyone would have any tips how to approach this.. I have looked at PowerBI storyteller, but it's like with a begin and end time and for me at least, it is not intuitive how i would transform this dataset in the storyteller visualisation.

Apart from the above, I wanted to make a heat map as well, with the locations of the players and how many times they are in an area on the pitch. Anyone have any idea how I can make like a heatmap but then on a visualisation of the football pitch?

Many thanks!

Comment: I hardly see PowerBI suitable for this type of visualisation. If you want to develop a web interface that visualise a football game with a field map and a timeline, you can do it with D3.js, but it's a lot of work...